# JPA CriteriaBuilder to get date values greater for a given time period

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I use 
criteriabuilder.ge() to get values greater to a given time period but getting compilation issue states following error;

```
The method ge(Expression<? extends Number>, Expression<? extends Number>) in the type CriteriaBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (Path, ParameterExpression<capture#6-of ? extends LocalDateTime>)
```

**Code**

```
  public Crud<T> greaterDate(String property, String value) {

    CriteriaBuilder cb = getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(getEntityClass());
    Root<T> root = cq.from(getEntityClass());
    ParameterExpression<? extends LocalDateTime> expression = cb.parameter(LocalDateTime.class);

    cq.select(root);


    Predicate predicate = cb.ge(root.get(getEntityType().getSingularAttribute(property)), expression);
```

How can I use ge/gt/lt for LocalDateTime  objects?

Comment: ge() applies to numbers. Use greaterThanOrEqual()

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you